# MySQL slow_log table: querying takes forever

Tags: mysql, performance, google-cloud-sql, slow-log

I'm running a query on the `slow_log`:

```
SELECT start_time FROM mysql.slow_log WHERE start_time < TIMESTAMP '2016-01-31 00:00:00'
```

Without a `WHERE` clause (using a `LIMIT`), the selects are fast.

However the `LIMIT` gives me the oldest logs, `ORDER BY` has the same problem for me.

Is this a MySQL thing, or does it have to do with the fact I'm running a Google Cloud SQL database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>*Answer originally left as a comment by [Michael - sqlbot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11651/michael-sqlbot):*</sub>

Mostly it's a MySQL thing.  The slow query log "table" -- by default -- is actually just a CSV file read by the "CSV storage engine," which emulates a table but uses a simple CSV file as its tablespace.

This allows appending to the slow query "table" to be a low overhead operation, but of course a CSV file has no indexes, so it has to be scanned from the beginning.

I haven't used Google Cloud SQL so I can't offer an authoritative answer on what options you might have, there, such as changing it to a MyISAM table and indexing it.

See [Selecting General Query and Slow Query Log Output Destinations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/log-destinations.html) in the product documentation.